# Set datetime to null Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How does one set a column with datatype datetime to null?

I searched through the docs and I couldn't find something towards that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this column is NULLABLE.
If it is - just use [UPDATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_examples) statement:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = NULL
WHERE myconditions
```

If it is REQUIRED - you can change REQUIRED to NULLABLE - [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#console_4)

[image]